# Which surds add to make a certain number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a list of surds.
The list goes like this:

- $\sqrt{2}$
- $\sqrt{3}$
- $\sqrt{5}$
- $\sqrt{6}$
- $\sqrt{7}$
- $\sqrt{8}$
- $\sqrt{10}$
- $\sqrt{11}$
- ...
- $\sqrt{99}$

---

- It is a list of every surd from $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{99}$.

Now say someone picks 3 surds, rounds the surds to 8 decimal places and adds them.
E.g. $$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{3} = 1.41421356 + 2.23606798 + 1.73205080 = 5.38233234$$

Is it possible to look at a number e.g. '5.38233234' and say which 3 surds were added to make it? If so how would a computer or human do it?

**Here is the code i made to find 2 numbers. It uses trial and error but is surprisingly fast:**

```
print("Enter a number above 8 dp")
num = float(input("> "))
for x in range(0,100):
    for y in range(0,100):
        if round(((x**0.5)+(y**0.5)),8) == round(num, 8):
            print(x)
            print(y)
```

And here is the code for a number containing 3 surds:

```
print("Enter a number above 8 dp")
num = float(input("> "))
for x in range(0,100):
    for y in range(0,100):
        for z in range(0,100):
            if round(((x**0.5)+(y**0.5)+(z**0.5)),8) == round(num, 8):
                print(x)
                print(y)
                print(z)
```

There is still however the problem that if a number contained lots of surds, it would take a long time to work it out using trial and improvement. I am still trying to find an algorithm to do this.

Comment: Just for the fun : if you round each of the considered surds to eight decimal places, you should get $$1.41421356+2.23606798+1.7320508\color{red}{1}=5.3823323\color{red}{5}$$ But, back to serious, as @lhf commented, this could be a quite easy programming exercise. May be, you could try by yourself. If, as I hope, you do it, update your post with your work since it will be interesting.

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest in this. Trial and improvement is an option but can be very slow scpecially if the number is made of lots of surds. I am wondering if there is an algorithm to do it.

Comment: It depends what you call a lot of surds, for sure. I am pretty sure that some heuristic methods could be involved. Continuing with the fun, give me a number and the number of surds (but do not exaggerate with the last !).

Comment: I amde it with 5 surds and it took a couple of seconds.

Comment: 3 numbers, 7.51398484503

Comment: 5,6,8. Where is the problem ?

Comment: Wow! How did you do it? Please can I see your code?

Comment: Show your work since you were supposed to try in Python and post your results.

Answer (score 2):

If you include numbers $\sqrt n$ for $n$ having a square factor then this is false: 
$$
\sqrt2+\sqrt2+\sqrt{12}
=
\sqrt3+\sqrt3+\sqrt{8}
$$

Otherwise, [Baker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem) implies that the sums are unique if computed with enough decimals.
It does not say anything about this case but short program confirms it.

Comment: Well, this is a good point. This means that we could find multiple solutions. This could be still interesting, don't you think ?

Comment: If duplicate surds are excluded, we would 'prevent' these solutions.